# Create rows and columns based on COUNT query

Tags: php, html, tablerow

Simple question I believe for anyone with minimal php skills (which I don't have sufficient amounts of haha)

```
$numrows = $retour['nb'] / 4;
echo $numrows;

echo "<table><tr>";
while ($callback = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryLocations2))
{   
echo utf8_encode('<td><img src="/flags/' . strtolower($callback['loc_code']) .  '.png" id="' . $callback['loc_id'] . '"><input type="checkbox" value="' .  $callback['loc_url'] . '" />' . $callback['loc_city'] . ', ' .  utf8_encode($callback['loc_state']) . '</td>');
}
echo "</tr></table>";
}
```

How would I go about presenting a table that will hold 4 results(4 columns) per row, based on the value of `$numrows`?

Thank you!

Comment: what results would be be getting back from the query?

Comment: The results are essentially an tiny image and a checkbox. I would like to have 4 images per row, hence the need for the $numrows variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output tr tags inside while loop:

```
$count = 0;
echo "<table>"; 
while ($callback = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryLocations2)) 
{    
    if ($count % 4 == 0)
        echo '<tr>';

    $count++;

    echo utf8_encode('<td><img src="/flags/' . strtolower($callback['loc_code']) .  '.png" id="' . $callback['loc_id'] . '"><input type="checkbox" value="' .  $callback['loc_url'] . '" />' . $callback['loc_city'] . ', ' .  utf8_encode($callback['loc_state']) . '</td>'); 

    if ($count % 4 == 0)
        echo '</tr>';
}

if ($count % 4 != 0)
{
    // need to add missing td-s here

    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This does not relate to the $numrows variable, and would print one row and one td for each query returned no?

Comment: No, you already iterate over a result set, which is $queryLocations

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you clearly, your initial code should work, what does it output then?

Comment: Well no my initial code makes no sense haha! I'm not using $numrows anywhere in my code, so all it does is one big row with 80 columns. I need to get x rows of 4 columns, where x is $numrows.

Comment: Now I get what you want. I'll fix my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try this!

Comment: Close but not quite, this returns 4 rows of 20 instead of the 20 rows of 4!

Comment: Yep, thought of $numrows as of number of columns, fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
$numrows = floor($retour['nb'] / 4);

echo $numrows;
$i=0;
echo "<table>";

while ($callback = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryLocations2))
{  
   if($i==4)

      {

         echo "<tr>"; 

         echo utf8_encode('<td><img src="/flags/' . strtolower($callback['loc_code']) .  '.png" id="' . $callback['loc_id'] . '"><input type="checkbox" value="' .  $callback['loc_url'] . '" />' . $callback['loc_city'] . ', ' .  utf8_encode($callback['loc_state']) . '</td>');

         echo "</tr>";

         $i=0;

      }

$i++;

}

while ($i<4) 
   { 

       echo '<td></td>';
       $i++;
   }

echo "</table>";

}



//if numrows used for # of rows then use following


$count=0;
while ($callback = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryLocations2) && $count<=$numrows)
{  

if($i==4)

echo "<tr>"; 

echo utf8_encode('<td><img src="/flags/' . strtolower($callback['loc_code']) .  '.png" id="' . $callback['loc_id'] . '"><input type="checkbox" value="' .  $callback['loc_url'] . '" />' . $callback['loc_city'] . ', ' .  utf8_encode($callback['loc_state']) . '</td>');

if($i==4)

{

   echo "</tr>"; 
   $i=0;
   $count++;

}

$i++;

}
while ($i<4) 

{ 
    echo '<td></td>';
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";

}
```